# phpMyAdmin CSV Upload Replace Data Not Working

Tags: sql, database, csv, phpmyadmin

I have created a database and table in phpMyAdmin.

I am importing the data from a csv file.

This works fine and adds the data correctly.

However each time I upload I want to replace the existing data.

I have ticked the box "Replace table data with file", it uploads fine but doesn't replace the existing rows it simply adds the new data as new rows below the old data.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be misleading text; it adds the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" directive rather than truncating the table prior to insert, see the bug report at: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4891/